# place cursor at end of value of input field on focus | angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a dynamic component being created and on `ngAfterViewInit` I've done the following code:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.input.nativeElement.focus();
}, 0);
```

This works: it sets the focus on the input correctly, but the cursor is placed at the beginning of the value. I would like to place the cursor at the end of the value.

I've tried this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.input.nativeElement.focus();
  let start = this.input.nativeElement.selectionStart;
  let end = this.input.nativeElement.selectionEnd;
  this.input.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(start,end);
}, 0);
```

I've also tried clearing the value and resetting it but cant get it to work.

Heres the html and how I'm accessing it:

```
<input class="nav-editor__input" #input type="text">

@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your input element `FormControl` or `ngModel`?

Comment: its not ng model

Comment: Then `FormControl`? For me works out of the box without jungling: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-53843529

Comment: `<input #input type="text">`

Comment: and im accessing with `@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;`

Comment: hmm yeah your example is working, thanks for dong that. should i switch to formcontrol?

Comment: When I do form/input/etc. I use Angular `ReactiveFormsModule` by default... `FormBuilder`, `FormControl`, `FormGroup` etc.. much more easier...

Comment: sounds good! ive switched my input to formcontrol, seems to work now. thank you!

Comment: Both are working btw :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using Angular Reactive Forms, it seams working out-of-the-box. Here is [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-53843529).

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Focus Test!</h1>
    <input #testInput type="text" [formControl]="formCtrl">
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  @ViewChild("testInput") testInput;

  formCtrl = this.fb.control('');

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formCtrl.setValue('Test');
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.testInput.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Setting focus in `ngAfterViewInit()`, puts cursor to the end of input value.

Here is [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-53843529-without-forms) without Reactive Forms.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Focus Test!</h1>
    <input #testInput type="text" [value]="value">
  `
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  name = 'Angular';

  value = '';

  @ViewChild("testInput") testInput;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.value = 'Test';
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.testInput.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

Also seems to be working out-of-the-box. However, Angular Reactive Forms is a bliss anyway.

Comment: thanks! ive reworked my component to use form builder, works now